# How to filter @ followed by an "a" element...and the following <br> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've changed my code, so now lets say there is this:

```
<p>
  <a href="#">@Mr. Jingles</a>
<br>
<br>
This would be where the person would say something.     // I want to start here
<br>
<br>
This is even more text.
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">@Lady Ladington</a>
<br>
<br>
Hello!
</p>
```

What I want to do is delete the first `<a>` element, then delete all of the `<br>` elements until where the person would say something.

When successful, it should look like:

```
<p>
This would be where the person would say something.
<br>
<br>
This is even more text.
</p>
<p>
Hello!
</p>
```

**Note:** These would be people commenting on a blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of using Regexp in the innerHtml property of the `<p></p>`.

```
function remove (elem, name) {
  var content = elem.innerHTML,
      regex = new RegExp('@<a.*?>' + name + '<\/a>(\n)*(<br\s?\/?>|\n)*', 'mgi');
  elem.innerHTML = content.replace(regex, '');
}

remove(paragr, 'Wiki Tiki');
```

And you should probably work on the regular expression, to handle all your scenarios, you could get newline characters `\n` and/or xhtml breaks `<br />`

Problem is that it's going to be a bit slow because of the innerHTML manipulation, but try it out, maybe it'll be fast enough.

Comment: I've changed the scenario and placed the @ inside of the `<a>`. How do I remove the first `<a>` then the following `<br>`s until where the comment starts.

Comment: I've already gotten past that with something else. I've placed the @ inside of the `<a>` so I could just use `.remove()` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's wrapped in an element with the ID of "theContent":

```
var content = document.getElementById('theContent');
var c = content.innerHTML;
c = c.replace(/@<a([^\/])+\/a>/,'');
c = c.replace(/(\<br>(\s)+)+/,'');
content.innerHTML = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to take into account some more checks, but it could be something like this:

```
$('p')
    .children().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && $(this).text() == '@';
    })
    .next('a')
    .nextUntil(':not(br)')
    .andSelf()
    .andSelf()
    .remove();
```

Also, this will not work in IE7 and earlier. For that use `this.nodeType == 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, I'm not sure how efficient it would be, and you may have to alter the logic depending on the text contained in your page -

```
$("p").contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("This would be") > -1) return false;
    $(this).remove()
})
```

The code just removes all nodes until it finds the text node with the words "This would be" in it.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/TTuDw/3/